# Multiplication of a 2D array by a 1D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, multiplication

I'm having trouble figuring out how to multiply the columns of a 2D array by a 1D array...

```
              Item

Store   0   1   2   3    4
 0      25  64  23  45  14
 1      12  82  19  34  63
 2      54  22  17  32  35

Item     Cost Per Item
   1           $12.00
   2           $17.95
   3           $95.00
   4           $86.50
   5           $78.00
```

I have to multiply the columns of the 2D array that symbolize the items by their cost (I.E. Column 1 2D array by the $12.00, Column 2 (2D array) by the $17.95.

What i'm mainly having trouble understanding is how to get the program to only multiply by the columns instead of the rows and columns, any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

```
import java.util.*;
public class asd
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double items[][]= new double[3][5];
        double cost[]=new double[5];
        loadArray(items, cost);
        System.out.println("Total amount of sales for each store : ");
        computeCost(items, cost);
        printArray(items, cost);
    }
    public static void loadArray(double items[][], double cost[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        int num, x, y;
        for(x=0; x<items.length;x++)
        {
            for(y=0; y<items[x].length; y++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the next item of data:");
                items[x][y]=input.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        //Cost of the items:
        cost[0]=12.99;
        cost[1]=17.95;
        cost[2]=95.00;
        cost[3]=86.50;
        cost[4]=78.00;
    }
    public static void printArray(double items[][], double cost[]) 
    {
        System.out.println("Number of items Sold During Day: ");
        int row, col;
        for (row =0;  row<items.length ; row++)
        {
            for(col=0; col<items[row].length; col++)
            {
                System.out.print( items[row][col]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Cost Per Item: ");
        int i;
        for (i =0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(cost[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void computeCost (double items[][], double cost[])
    {
        int row, col;
        double productArray[]=new double[5];
        for (row =0;  row<items.length ; row++)
        {
            for(col=0; col<items[1].length; col++)
            {
                productArray[row]=items[row][col] * cost[0];
            }
            System.out.println("TEST: "+productArray[row]);
        }
    }
}
```

The loop would have to do this for the first column:

```
         double a,b,c;
        a=items[0][0]*cost[0];
        System.out.println("Test 12.99*25: "+a);
        b=items[1][0]*cost[0];
        System.out.println("Test 12.99*12: "+b);
        c=items[2][0]*cost[0];
        System.out.println("Test 12.99*54: "+c);
```

Edit: I finished the program thanks for the help to the people who commented.